# A more consise way of executing code once only in C?

Tags: c, boolean, conditional-statements

I often have code of the form:

```
uint8_t bool_var = 0;

for (;;) {
    ...
    if (!bool_var) {
       do_something();
       bool_var = 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a more concise, non-macro, way of expressing the if condition and block?

Comment: You'll have to expand the context, because code in general will only run once unless you do something to make it run again like putting it in a loop.

Comment: Looks perfectly readable and concise to me. In C++ you could do some tricks with functors, but in plain C anything shorter is going to make it cryptic IMO.

Comment: `if(!bool_var++)`. But your version is more readable.

Comment: @DavideVisentin - So only don't enter this block again for 255 iterations?

Comment: @DavideVisentin I'd been thinking along that line, but eventually it will wrap, especially on ATMEGAs with `uin8_t`s.

Comment: Yes I was thinking to it before the question was edited. You are all right.

Comment: if you exclude macros for hiding code I think that is the best way. If you have `for(int i=0; i<...; ++i)` you could remove the boolean variable and replace it with `if (i==0)` but other than that...

Comment: Although... If `bool_var` was `_Bool` instead, I think @DavideVisentin's suggestion would work like a charm, since the result will always be clamped to `[0, 1]`.

Comment: You can write something cryptic and ugly like `static bool execute_once=true; ... execute_once && (do_something(), (execute_once=false));`. I wouldn't call that better than your present code though, and the machine code generated is probably about the same.

Comment: What about `if(!(bool_var && bool_var|=1))`?

Comment: @StoryTeller I'd forgotten about `_Bool`.  If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: you can do `if (!bool_var && bool_var = 1) {` too, but that's confusing :)

Comment: `#define once static int done_##__LINE__ = 0; while (!done_##__LINE__ && ++done_##__LINE__)` Usage: `once { do_something(); }`

Comment: @n.m. Just to be mean: `once { do_something(); } once { do_something(); } // end of line`  :)

Comment: @Lundin Hmm, can that be overcome with the use of the `#line` preprocessor directive?

Comment: @Lundin of course you can break it in many different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is about as readable and simple as it can get for the majority of cases.

---

For very specific purposes however, you could find yourself in a situation where you want to always call a function but sometimes without an effect. Then it could perhaps make sense to use some trick with function pointers:

```
typedef void func_t (void);
...
func_t* do_stuff = do_something;
... 

while(stuff) // this code can't be changed for whatever reason
{
  do_stuff();
}
```

In such a scenario you can come up with this:

```
void nop (void) {}
...
do_stuff = nop;
```

Now you can keep calling `do_stuff` but nothing will happen.